# Can /etc/apache2 directory on Sierra work on High-Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, osx-server, apache, webserver

My question is related to the following:

"Apache not working with user Sites folder on macOS 10.13 High Sierra"

I installed High-Sierra over Sierra, and all my localhost/~username/pages were inaccessible.  I restored my backed-up Sierra system.  Now I'm wondering if that /etc/apache2 directory would have worked on High-Sierra.  It has a 'users' directory with username.conf setups for all the /Users who use this machine, each having their own web-pages in their own Sites, and their own sub-directories in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables.

Several wab-pages have <form action> .... </form> structures that send <input name values> to scripts which process them and return web-pages, which may, in turn. be sent back for further processing.  In other words, it's a design that allows a continuing dialog.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you update your Server app after the macOS upgrade?

Comment: I tried a lot of things to get it to work, but there are no instructions about what to change.  The 'httpd.conf' just points to '/Library/WebServer/Documents' as the place to put web pages, which would cause confusion between the several /Users who have individual Sites.  And it seems all existing bookmarks would need to be revised in some fashion to reference existing html pages.  Is there a tutorial on how to 'update'?

Comment: PS: what do you mean by 'Server app'?  My Mac is my server, and my browsers are my clients.

Comment: Because you tagged your question with osx-server, I assumed you are using Apple‘s Server app to setup a web server. If not, please explain in your question how you‘ve  setup your server.

Comment: By 'Apple Server app', do you mean on an iPhone?  I have a Macbook Pro, and never heard of an 'Apple Server app'..Is there one built-in to High-Sierra?

Comment: [This macOS Server app.](https://www.apple.com/macos/server/servers-made-easy/) But to just serve websites, there are [alternatives like MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/), so it is necessary that you update your question regarding how you have setup your webserver. Please also elaborate on how it worked before the upgrade, and what exactly happened after the upgrade.

Comment: not2savvy, I've been doing MacOS web-services since Tiger (10.4) using what came built-in to the Mac.  I wrote an extensive description of the modifications I needed to make, and created a publicly accessible version of it at  - http://web.stanford.edu/group/spires/uspires/suspires/suspires.mac1.html - What has 'changed' in High-Sierra is the elimination of individual '/User/uname/Sites', while retaining all the 'cgi-bin' logic.  I just need to get 'localhost/~uname/page.html' working again.